# Google Chrome does not show cookie values anymore

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Today I saw that I can't inspect cookie values anymore in google chrome, it only shows me the cookie names but there is no possibility anymore to view the value. Is there a way how to fix this? It's important for me as developer...
(I did not find anything on the internet)

This is how it looks like now:
[image: Google Chrome new cookie UI]

Answer (score 7):

Paste this URL into Chrome and enable the option to get the menu back:

chrome://flags/#page-info-cookies-subpage

[image]

Comment: This worked for a while, but doesn't anymore (on Chrome 114).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this as well.

- You can of course still check what cookies a website uses via `Inspect` -> `Application` tab -> `Cookies`.
  [image]
- Alternatively, there is the [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) extension, which can also be used to view (and edit!)
  cookies.

As dside noticed, this is only true for first-party cookies. Third-party are not shown anymore. Chrome wants to move away from those anyway, so this might have sth to do with that decision.
https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/

Comment: No all of them though. The cookie viewer from the address bar was able to show cookies "from other sites", e.g. set by CORS requests. Neither dev tools nor extensions are able to show those.

Comment: In addition, I have 2 PCs with the same version of Chrome. One of them showing old UI (has menu items Cookies, allows to view cookie content) but another one has new UI (does not have Cookies but has Cookies and site data, does not allow to view content)

Comment: It's possible that this is part of the move away from third-party cookies. https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/